# Java: How to read a simple web server get-request

Tags: java, sockets, character-encoding, webserver, get-request

So here is the code for my simple webserver simulation

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public final class WebServer {

    final class HTTPRequest {
        final static String CRLF = "\r\n";
        Socket socket;

        public HTTPRequest(Socket socket)
        {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public void processRequest() throws IOException
        {
            InputStream clientIn = this.socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream clientOut = this.socket.getOutputStream();

            BufferedReader clientReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(clientIn, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

            String requestLine = clientReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(requestLine);

            String headerLine = null;
            while((headerLine = clientReader.readLine()) != null && headerLine.length() != 0)
                System.out.println(headerLine);

            clientOut.close();
            clientReader.close();
            this.socket.close();
        }
    }


    private int portNumberErrorFix(int n)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int result = 0;
        switch(n)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                System.out.print("ERROR!!!\nThe port number given is out of the proper range(1024 > port number < 65535). Please enter a new Port Number:");
                result = in.nextInt();
            }

            case 1:
            {
                System.out.print("ERROR!!!)\nThe port number given could not be used. Please enter a new port number as a number between 1024 and 65535:");
                if(in.hasNextInt())
                    result = in.nextInt();
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }
        if(result > 1024 && result < 65535)
            return result;
        else 
            return 0;
    }

    private int readArgs(String argument)
    {
        int portNumber = 0;
        try{
            portNumber = Integer.parseInt(argument);

            while(portNumber < 1024 || portNumber > 65535)
            {
                portNumber = portNumberErrorFix(0);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            while(portNumber == 0)
                portNumber = portNumberErrorFix(1);
        }

        return portNumber;
    }


    private void runServer(int portNum) throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket welcome = new ServerSocket(portNum);

        while(true)
        {
            Socket clientConnection = welcome.accept();
            HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(clientConnection);
            request.processRequest();
        }
    }

    public void controller(String argument)
    {
        int portNumber = readArgs(argument);
        try {
            runServer(portNumber);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!!!\nServer startup could not be performed");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebServer test = new WebServer();
        if(args.length > 0)
            test.controller(args[0]);
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No commands given in the command line, please try again");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```

my overall objective at this point is to be able to read a GET request line and headers made by my web-browser to my program(e.x. if i run my code and type "https://localhost:9876/index.html" into my chrome web browser I should read a request line and header information on my webserver. Now it is reading the request and printing with out error, but it is obviosuly in a unknown charset for my buffer

[image: output]

If you look at my imports you can see I've tried a multitude of solutions I have found on this site, but so far none have worked.

Edit 1: I have tried Roman idea to make sure the Eclipse console isnt the cause of this by changing the default charset on the console but got this result[image]

Comment: Also if it helps anything, I am using Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 IDE for coding and testing purposes if that makes any difference. Although I have tested it on Linux genome terminal and found similar results

Comment: Did you run it in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes i did, the image above is directly from the Eclipse console

Comment: I have also tried using a GZIPInpustream which would throw a null exception, assigning my inputstreamreader with a different charset[i.e. new InputStreamReader(clientIn, charset.forName("UTF-8")] which just returned less squares and more question marks from the image above.

Comment: @spstephens I've just tried your code, and it works fine. So it must be an Eclipse thing.